# Why does "Read more" link not show up on view, but "Add new comment" does?

Tags: 7, comments

As said in the title, I'm having a problem with the "read more" link.
I made my own view (wie-zijn-we-pagina) and content type (wie-zijn-we-) and am trying to add a custom "read more" and "add new comment" link to it. The code that I'm using gives me the correct custom "Add new comment" link but the "Read more" link doesn't work. At first it didnt even show up.

My code:

```
function ap_hogeschool_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables){
$variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-comments'] = FALSE; 
if($variables['view'] && $variables['type'] == 'wie_zijn_we_')
    {   
    $variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] ='<div class="custom-add-read-more"> </div>';
    $variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['node-readmore']['html'] = TRUE;
    $variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['title'] = '<div class="custom-add-comment"> </div>';
    $variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['html'] = TRUE;

} 
}
```

I don't know if the part where i call the view and content type is correct... I'm still a new drupal user.

An image of what i have:

[image]

An image of what in need to have:

[image]

Could somebady please help me along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake on your code. Instead of `$variables['content']['links']['node']` you wrote `$variables['content']['links']['comment']`.

Corrected code:

```
function ap_hogeschool_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables){

  $variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-comments'] = FALSE;

  if( $variables['type'] == 'wie_zijn_we_' && $variables['view_mode'] == 'teaser' ){

     $variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] ='<div class="custom-add-read-more"> </div>';
     // Mistake was in this line:
     $variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['html'] = TRUE;
     $variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['title'] = '<div class="custom-add-comment"> </div>';
     $variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']['html'] = TRUE;

   } 
  }
```

Comment: Hey Rufein, thx alot, This work perfectly. Again a dum mistake from my part :(.

Comment: Don't worry, everybody learns making mistakes. We are here to learn. Good luck on your project.

Comment: Eu Rufein, I just noticed. I can see my custom link now but it can't be clicked, its like the link part is missing and it just shows a nice picture now... Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it's OK. You could check with firebug if an <a> wrapper is printed in code. This tag should wrap the title you have writted in your preproccess hook. If it's printed, then with CSS you will solve the problem.

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't work at all. There is one post where the "add new comment" works but on all the other posts it does not place a <a> wrapper around the links... Is it possible that my new class go's in conflict with the one from my front page? (if I use the first part of the following code: if($variables['view'] && $variables['type'] == 'wie_zijn_we_')   then i get tons of errors on my view saying that it doesn't accept view as a variable or something.)

Comment: I've corrected the code. `$vatiables['view']` is the object view that has been passed by VIEWS module like an arguemnt. For example, When you see an 'article' content type, VIEWS module is not building the page (unless you add a view in this page). So it doesn´t exist this variable in a typical context when a node is built. Probably that´t the reason of errors

Comment: Hey Rufein. That was wat I was looking for and it works, I now only apply this where I need it so thats great.        But the problem I had before is still there. It only places an <a> wrapper around the first "add new content" link and all the other links it places in a <span> wrapper. Do you have any idee why it works like that? On my front page this code works without trouble, but on the view it doesn't...

Comment: 2 things to consider. First of all, you make sure that in views module, in the _show : Content_ is active the _teaser view_. Then, if you are displaying this view in front-page, you should remember that content types are printed in front page once you have published. You can uncheck the _promoted to front page_ in every content and there won´t appear it- You can also make this option unchecked by default if you edit your content type.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my problem. I put a trial version of my website online ( http://stucrew-stucrew.rhcloud.com/ ) If you go to this website and click on the highest link (ALGEMENE STUDENTENRAAD AP) then you get to the page that I'm working on. The problem is with the small icons (the links). You will see that only the most right one has a <a> wrapper and the rest just <span> wrappers. If you can take a look it would be much appreciated :s .    Btw: on my front page all of this works without a problem.

Comment: I just tried to play with it some more, and now I found out that if I completly removed the code out of my template file The "Link" is completly gone. No "Read more" or "Add new comment" links are showing up. So I went back to my display suit but there it says that it should be showing up in the correct region... I realy have no clue why it doesn't show up :(

Comment: Yesterday i couldn`t take a look to the trial version that you uploaded. The link is not working right now. If you put online, i 'll probably find the solution.

Comment: O, Ill take a look why its not working and try t fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: http://wazaa-stucrew.rhcloud.com : This is the new link to the website. There was somthing wrong with the host proces, but with a new install it works again. The rest stays the same (choose the top link (ALGEMENE STUDENTENRAAD AP) to go to the page that im working on.)           I tested some more and found that the problem only shows up when I use my self made view type ("Wie_zijn_we_pagina") if I change this on my view to "teaser" of "full view", the code works ...

Comment: Very nice page!!! It`s as you say. You have to change to "teaser". This mode only displays teasers. If the problem persist, make a screenshot capture of your view configuration page and upload here to take a look.

Comment: Is there no way to use a self made view mode to do this? I mean I need 7 different ways to display this page (just talking about the colours of the name and of the little icons). And if I use a teaser view isnt that going to conflict with the teaser view that I use on my front page (Its different)?

Comment: It easier change the CSS. I understand what you want. Each view has itw own color. For example, (ALGEMENE STUDENTENRAAD AP) is red and GEZONDHEID EN WELZIJN is blue. [Descendant Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) in CSS is the best solution. Each view has a div wrapper with an unique id and classes. For example: `.view-id-view_wie_zijn_we__  .node-readmore{ ... CSS attributes ...}` This way you could overwrite the default CSS that you writed

Comment: Hey Rufein that works realy good indeed but it gives me a follow up problem. The teaser view regions of my front page and my view aren't the same. The teaser view itself is bigger and arranged differently on my view. Should I compansate the difference with css?

Comment: nvm, I was able to finish it using just css. Once again thank you very very much for all the help. You realy are the best. (When I have the time ill update my online trial so you can see what became of it.)

Comment: Hey Rufein, sorry to bother you again but could you plz take a look at this. Its a new probleme I have but I think it has the same soultion like you gave already. Thx up front (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72534/how-can-i-change-the-default-link-to-the-email-contact-form)